Stripe Payment flow using js
I am struggling with implementing payment flow on the website. To charge a customer using Stripe, do I need both a SetupIntent and a PaymentIntent? I want to save the customer's card information at the time of payment so that I can use it in the future to charge the customer.
I am currently using stripe for user payment.  So, we are having a Signup page for a user from where user can enter the password and confirms it and then clicks on submit. After submiting the user info I am doing below flow

Create customer for that user in stripe using name and email.
Then call createsetupIntent stripe API which returns clientsecret use that clientsecret to show paymentelement to the user.
Payment popup contains stripe paymentelement and Pay button.
When user clicks the pay button I am saving card info of the user in stripe using confirmParams.
After that, setting that method as defaultmethod.
And finally use paymentIntentAPI to charge a customer with specific amount.
If payment is successful then every month my system will charge a customer using Invoice API. because, I am not using subscription based model.

Is that flow correct. Or is there any other way to make it more efficient? And how to handle failure cases here like after clcks on Pay button if there is a failure while saving card info or charge a customer then how to handle those cases?

You don't need both a SetupIntent and PaymentIntent - SetupIntents are used to save the card without a payment.
To save a card during a payment, you can use PaymentIntents. The PaymentIntent that saves the card is set with setup_future_usage='off_session' while the PaymentIntent(s) that use the saved card is(are) set with off_session=true.
This is the guide for this flow:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-during-payment

Create customer for that user in stripe using name and email.
Then call createPaymentIntent stripe API (setup_future_usage) which returns clientsecret use that clientsecret to show paymentelement to the user.
Payment popup contains stripe paymentelement and Pay button.
When user clicks the pay button I am saving card info of the user in stripe using confirmPayment.
(When I want to charge the Customer) use paymentIntent API (off_session) to charge a customer with specific amount.

I misunderstood the points about setting the payment method as default / Invoicing. You can indeed set the payment_method_id as the Customer's invoice_settings.default_payment_method, then create an Invoice for the Customer, which will automatically charge the default Payment Method and create a PaymentIntent.

Thank you for your feedback. I just have a doubt regarding creating a PaymentIntent and creating an invoice. Does creating a PaymentIntent automatically create an invoice? Because after payment using PaymentIntent, I want to send an invoice to the customer.

No, creating an Invoice automatically creates a Payment Intent, but not the other way around. For recurring payments, you can just create the invoice. If you also want an invoice for the first payment, then you should save the card with a setup_intent then create an invoice.

Thank you so much for providing the answer to my query.
